# how view count number vote fivestar on comment?

Tags: views, comments, nodes, rating

it like this.
examp:

- 5 star ***** (15)
- 4 star **** (150)
- 3 star *** (2)
- 2 star ** (0)
- 1 star * (12)

now.

- 15 is number comment vote 5star for node this
- 150 is number comment vote 4star for node this
- 2 is number comment vote 3star for node this
  ....

This examp other:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check this page at Drupal.org: [Fivestar 7.x: Creating a User Comment/Rating and Average Rating for a Content type](https://www.drupal.org/node/1308114).

If you use the [Fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar) voting module, your content will have own rating and reviews, and each contents each comment will have its own rating and review.

Comment: oh. Thanks but I want count and show number vote for 5 star, 4 star....